# Фильтр по нескольким параметрам Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть фильтр товаров. Все отлично работает, но только тогда, когда фильтрую по одному параметру. То есть, какой параметр фильтра в коде ниже, тот и работает.
Понимаю что в return надо объединить все выводы с фильтра, но не знаю как это сделать

```
var main = new Vue({
el: '#main',
data: {
layout: 'grid',
search: { countries: [], brends: [], areas: [], rains: [], dotstarts: [], categoryids: [] },
items: [
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    {
        "title": "<?php the_title(); ?>",
        "categoryid": "<?php echo "$catid"; ?>",
        "price": "<?php the_field('price'); ?>",
        "brend": "<?php echo $brend['value']; ?>",
        "country": "<?php echo $country['value']; ?>",
        "area": "<?php echo $area['value']; ?>",
        "rain": "<?php echo $rain['value']; ?>",
        "dotstart": "<?php echo $dotstart['value']; ?>"
    },
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    ]
 },
computed: {
    filteredItems() {
    return this.items.filter(item => {
        if (this.search.countries.length > 0) {
            return this.search.countries.indexOf(item.country) > -1;
        }
        if (this.search.brends.length > 0) {
            return this.search.brends.indexOf(item.brend) > -1;
        }
        if (this.search.areas.length > 0) {
            return this.search.areas.indexOf(item.area) > -1;
        }
        if (this.search.rains.length > 0) {
            return this.search.rains.indexOf(item.rain) > -1;
        }
        if (this.search.dotstarts.length > 0) {
            return this.search.dotstarts.indexOf(item.dotstart) > -1;
        }
        if (this.search.categoryids.length > 0) {
            return this.search.categoryids.indexOf(item.categoryid) > -1;
        }
        return item;
        })
       }
     } 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если стоит задача сделать быстро и с минимальными изменениями в коде, то можно просто каждое условие добавлять в массив (далеко не самый лучший вариант, просто первое что приходит в голову):

```
filteredItems() {
    return this.items.filter(item => {
        let conditions = [true];
        if (this.search.countries.length > 0) {
            conditions.push(this.search.countries.indexOf(item.country) > -1);
        }
        if (this.search.brends.length > 0) {
            conditions.push(this.search.brends.indexOf(item.brend) > -1);
        }
        if (this.search.areas.length > 0) {
            conditions.push(return this.search.areas.indexOf(item.area) > -1);
        }
        if (this.search.rains.length > 0) {
            conditions.push(this.search.rains.indexOf(item.rain) > -1);
        }
        if (this.search.dotstarts.length > 0) {
            conditions.push(this.search.dotstarts.indexOf(item.dotstart) > -1);
        }
        if (this.search.categoryids.length > 0) {
            conditions.push(return this.search.categoryids.indexOf(item.categoryid) > -1);
        }
       return conditions.every(condition => condition);
   })
}
```

Comment: Супер, работает) Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вот так попробовал:

```
        return this.items.filter(item => {
            if (this.search.countries.length > 0 && this.search.countries.indexOf(item.country) === -1) { // если существует условие сортировки, но у item нет такого значения
                return false;
            }
            if (this.search.brends.length > 0 && this.search.brends.indexOf(item.brend) === -1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.search.areas.length > 0 && this.search.areas.indexOf(item.area) === -1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.search.rains.length > 0 && this.search.rains.indexOf(item.rain) === -1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.search.dotstarts.length > 0 && this.search.dotstarts.indexOf(item.dotstart) === -1) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.search.categoryids.length > 0 && this.search.categoryids.indexOf(item.categoryid) === -1) {
                return false
            }
            return true; // возвращяем item, если он соответсвует всем условиям выше
        })
```